# RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established when Node version set to 10x

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

We are using AWS Lambda to call our API's. We recently upgraded our Lambda Node version from 8.10 to Node 10.x version. We have added process event for unhandled rejection and also written code in try-catch block but none of the code resolves our issue. Please find the error block that we are getting when we hit the API through Lambda.

Please note that we are using promise-request NPM package for request.

Tried code with Try catch and handling unhandled event using Process.event

```
 {
  "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
  "errorMessage": "RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
  "stack": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
    "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:203:15)",
    "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
    "    at /var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:199:33",
    "    at activeFireEvent (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:242:44)",
    "    at fireRejectionEvent (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:632:14)",
    "    at Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:65:9)",
    "    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:44:14)",
    "    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)",
    "    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)",
    "    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)",
    "    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)"
  ],
  "reason": {
    "errorType": "RequestError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
    "stack": [
      "RequestError: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established",
      "    at new RequestError (/var/task/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)",
      "    at Request.plumbing.callback (/var/task/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)",
      "    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/var/task/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)",
      "    at self.callback (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)",
      "    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)",
      "    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
      "    at Request.onRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)",
      "    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)",
      "    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
      "    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)",
      "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)",
      "    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
      "    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)",
      "    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)",
      "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
    ],
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to Node.js 12.x, which is possible now, avoids the issue.

Comment: I'm running into this error and upgrading to node.js 12.x does not avoid the issue in my case

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, and its been 6 months that I had upgraded my Lambda to 12.X but, I still get the same errors at times, "Client network socket disconnected before a secure TLS connection was established". I have also added an environment variable NODE_OPTIONS: --tls-min-v1.0. But it seems the error suddenly re-appears leading to service failure.